# How to access deserialized nested SObjects

Tags: rest-service, deserialize

I am implementing a custom REST API to support upserting a related set of records, similar to the [Salesforce composite REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm). Main reason for that is because I want all DML operations to be part of a single transaction. I have a problem accessing the child records in the nested structure after deserializing them. For example, I can successfully deserialize a nested JSON structure containing one parent and one child record, both custom objects. Here's how I am doing that (just muck-about code while I get it going):

```
    while (parser.nextToken() != Null) {
        if (parser.getCurrentName() == 'records') {
            parser.nextValue();
            parents = (list<Parent_Object__c>)parser.readvalueas(list<SObject>.class);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Once that runs, I have the parent record(s) and can upsert them. I can also see that the child records are in the data structure, both from debug log and because if I serialize it back by calling JSON.serialize(parents) and check in the generated JSON. Here's the part of the System.debug(parent) with the child record in it:

```
...., "child_objects__r":[{"s":3,"v":{"new_control_systems_ (2 more) ...":"switch_only_1","quantity__c":"17","attributes":{"type":"child_object__c"}}}], ....
```

However, the problem comes when I try to get hold of a child to upsert it. Here's what I have:

```
for (Child_Object__c c: parent.Child_Objects__r) {
    c.parent__c = parent.Id;
    children.add(c);
}
```

It never gets into that loop.

I'm thinking I might change things to just pass through a flat list of SObjects to upsert but was hoping to keep close the spirit of the Salesforce composite API call and the parent child info is implicit in the structure.

Here's a cut down version of the JSON I am passing in:

```
{
    "records": [
        "custom_field__c": "blah",
        "ext_id__c": "abc123",
        "attributes": {
            "referenceId": "abc123",
            "type": "Parent_Object__c"
        },
        "child_objects__r": {
            "done": false,
            "totalSize": 1,
            "records": [
                {
                    "cust_field__c": "abc",
                    "child_ext_id__c": "abc123-1",
                    "attributes": {
                        "referenceId": "abc123-1",
                        "type": "Child_Object__c"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Added the "done" and "totalSize" after reviewing what Salesforce creates when serializing SObjects. Makes no difference if I set "done" to true or false.

Comment: Should the inner loop be over `parent.Child_Objects__r.records`? That is where all the field values will be.

Comment: Just tried... when I change it to `Parent_Object__c.Child_Objects__r.records`, it doesn't compile. I get the error "Invalid foreign key relationship: Parent_Object__c.Child_Objects__r"

Comment: I wonder if having the `__c` and `__r` suffixes in your JSON is causing some confusion. I might be easier to have distinct names in you JSON that don't follow Salesforce custom object and relationship naming conventions. Less likely to get mixed up.

Comment: I did that because that is how the composite API call does. Just tried changing Child_Objects__r to something else but I get an error upon deserializing: "System.JSONException: No such column 'Child_Objects' on sobject of type Parent_Object__c". Of course I could have whatever conventions I want but am trying to make it so I can just call `parser.readvalueas(list<SObject>.class)` and not do lots of explicit JSON parsing.

Comment: Maybe you could do a System.debug of `parent` before your for loop to see what state it is in. Or even serialize it again to see if it matches the input JSON.

Comment: Yes, I had a look at that already. The differences when I re-serialize it are that it has a key value entry for the child record, like so:
`"records": {"item 1": {"cust_field__c": "abc" ......}}`
Guess I can try to match that on input instead of having the list of records. Where the record is actually in the database, the "item 1" is replaced with the Id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39479/discussion-between-donmac23-and-daniel-ballinger).